# Entity Framework 7 - The property cannot exist on entity type 'object' because the property is not marked as shadow state

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I spend couple of days trying to solve following error on my Entity Framework 7 data mode:

**The property 'CreatedById' cannot exist on entity type 'object' because the property is not marked as shadow state and n o corresponding CLR property exists on the underlying type.**

I'm getting such errors for all of the Foreign Keys which I want to define explicit.

I got following entities:

```
public abstract class Entity
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ChangedOn { get; set; }

    public int ChangedById { get; set; }

    public Account ChangedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Account: Entity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class Project: Entity
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Project have to have name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Vcs { get; set; }

    public string VcsPath { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }        
}
```

And this is my OnModelCreating() method:

```
public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        //builder.Entity<Entity>(baseEntity =>
        //{
        //    baseEntity.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        //    baseEntity.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        //    baseEntity.Property(p => p.ChangedOn).IsRequired();
        //    baseEntity.Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRequired();
        //    baseEntity.HasOne(e => e.ChangedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ChangedById);
        //});

        builder.Entity<Project>(project =>
        {
            project.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            project.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            project.Property(p => p.ChangedOn).IsRequired();
            project.Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRequired();
            project.HasOne(e => e.ChangedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ChangedById);
        });
}
```

And then I'm trying to generate migration: **dnx ef Migrations add Initial** I'm getting:
The property 'CreatedById' cannot exist on entity type 'object' because the property is not marked as shadow state and n o corresponding CLR property exists on the underlying type.

Here is just an example for CreateById but I'm getting this error for all of the foreign keys.

Can somebody tell me what is going on?

Comment: I don't see any `CreatedById` in your code. Do you have an existing database?

Comment: Could you also provide your DbContext ctor?